# Get elements by name IE8 on different tab (Javascript)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, coypu

I am developing on a program in C# that automates inputting information into a website. This program uses a library (Coypu) that allows this and for the execution of Javascript to manipulate further.

The problem comes in two forms:

- The website only uses names (not ids) for its objects and I must use IE8 for them. Therefore I cannot use `document.getElementsByName('name');` because it's not supported in earlier versions of IE.
- I found a workaround by utilizing the form that's on the site but am having trouble using it because the site has to click a link to create a second tab for itself, leaving me helpless in grabbing the form in the second tab. Using something like `document.forms[formIndex].elements['elementsName'];` (although the tab appears to have focus) only gives me the forms from the main tab.

Has anyone ever fixed this problem or found a workaround in Javascript? Also, I'm not sure if jQuery can be used in my scenario as the Javascript is a string passed in to a C# method. However, it may or may not work.

Answer (score 0):

If the website you are testing has access to jQuery you can use Coypu to populate specific fields in their respective forms:

e.g.

```
void PopulateInputField(int formName, string fieldName, string fieldValue)
{
    browser.ExecuteScript(string.Format("$('form[name='{0}'] > input[name='{1}']).val('{2}')", formName, fieldName, fieldIndex));
}
```

Note how the C# string passed to Coypu's ExecuteScript contains the jQuery.